# How do I create a vertex at the intersecting point of two intersecting edges without addon or scripts, no faces involved?

Tags: modeling

[image: Screenshot]
As seen in the screenshot, I'm using version 2.79 . Is it possible to do it with plain blender, without installing addons?

Answer (score 2):

If doing that without addons you need to subdivide both edges and use snapping tools to snap vertex from one of the edges to another.

In ideal situation, your edges will be aligned with the world axes. However this is not always the case, hence this solution assumes they aren't (it still works even if they are) and uses custom transform orientation for snapping vertices. Alternatively it's possible to align view to the selected edge and use *View* transform orientation, although it might be less convenient navigating in the viewport.

1. With edge selected, create Custom [Transform Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (or from the Properties shelf > Transform Orientations rollout). Note that *Selection mode* should be set to *Edge* so transform orientation is created for it. By default this transform orientation will be selected as current one; if not, choose it in the Transform Orientations menu or with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

   [image]
2. Enable [*Snap during transform*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping) tool. Set *Type of Element to snap to* to *Vertex* (or *Edge* depending on which element you will hover over to snap vertex to). Set [Pivot point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html) to *Active Element* to use active selection as pivot.

   [image]
3. Subdivide one of the edges once (<kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide* with edge selected).
4. Select vertex created after subdividing, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select corner vertex of the edge to scale to. Activate Scale tool with <kbd>S</kbd> to move the vertex, press adjacent axis name twice to use custom transform axes and hover mouse over the vertex of the edge to snap to (or edge itself depending on what you selected in step 2).

   [image]
5. Do the same for the other edge.

   [image]
6. Select all and use <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* to join 2 vertices into one vertex at the intersection.

   [image]

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm stuck/lost at step 4. [link](https://imgur.com/UDwki9H) which one is the corner vertex? And I have to _scale_ to _move_?

Comment: @BlenderNoob the vertex made by subdividing is to the left or to the right of the edge you want to snap it to. You want to move it to the intersection of the edges, so in case of the linked image to the left from the selected vertex. Thus with that selected you select one to the left and scale with Pivot as active. Alternatively instead of Scaling use Grabbing with G and grab vertex to the edges intersection, the result will be the same.

Comment: I have spent the last 6 hours trying to follow step 4 instructions and another couple trying to upload motion screencast of what I am doing. Both fail. There is something wrong with my head here. Everytime I scale, results don't look like as pictured. One edge fly to Japan and the other to Spain. Now I mark my beginning of step 4 screenshot with letters [here](https://i.imgur.com/JnuXEmy.png). It's just after I subdivided. Would you kindly please instruct, what should I do to which vertex.

Comment: @BlenderNoob according to the screenshot options are set as they should be for this to work. There are 2 ways - scaling to active and grabbing. If scaling, select vertex E, then Shift select vertex A. Enable scaling tool with S, press X or Y (depends on your transform orientation) twice and hover mouse over the vertex B. Second way - select only vertex E, press G, X or Y twice and hover over the vertex B. This is more complex to describe than do so it's seems too long.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select on the of the edges. Press W and subdivide the edge.
2. Select the new vertex you created. Move it to the point of intersection.
3. Delete the other edge. The vertices should still be left over.
4. Select one of the vertices on the side (from the edge you just deleted) and select the vertex at the intersection. Press F to join them into an edge. Do the same to the vertex on the other side.

Comment: Including images could help clarifying the answer. Precision in the point 2 is the most interesting.

Comment: Indeed. In point 2, is it possible to snap the created vertex to the point of intersection?

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but practical.

In edit mode, with snap target set to edge.

1. Two coplanar edges, both selected.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > 'Subdivide'. (Create a vertex on both edges)
3. <kbd>F</kbd> (Connect your new vertices)
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>(Create a custom orientation from one of your original edges)... and ....  <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> translate that edge's new vertex along it. Hover over the other edge, it will snap. as you move the cursor over the point of intersection, it will become more accurate.
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, (Merge at: whichever vertex is on the intersection)

[image: Steps]

Comment: If you could create a custom orientation for snapping (projection)  as quickly as you can create a custom orientation for transforms, it would hugely increase the capability of the snapping system, without adding loads of buttons or menus.....